# Find the positive values of x for which the series x^ln(n) n=2 to infinity converges

Tags: calculus

I know its a geometric series so I figured it would be x from 0 to 1, but I got the wrong answer.

Comment: "...for which the series... **converges** ? And if it is $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{\log n}\;$$ then it is *not* a geometric series.

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$x^{\ln n}=(e^{\ln x})^{\ln n}=(e^{\ln n})^{\ln x}=n^{\ln x}.$$

Recall that $\sum n^{k}$ converges if and only if $k\lt -1$ ("$p$-series").

Comment: +1 for **not** writing $\sum\frac1{n^p}$ (I've never understood why people insist on writing that instead of $\sum n^{-p}$; doing the latter would have given us a different Riemann $\zeta$ function...).